# Error when I try to access structure with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, data-structures, segmentation-fault

```
struct cars {
   char  color[50];
   int maxSpeed;
   float consumption;
};


int main() 
{
  struct cars car1;
  struct cars car2;
  struct cars * car3;

  //Car 1
  strcpy( car1.color, "red");
  car1.maxSpeed = 140;
  car1.consumption = 6.6;

  //Car 2
  strcpy( car2.color, "blue");
  car2.maxSpeed = 150;
  car2.consumption = 7.3;

  //Car 3
  strcpy( car3->color, "green");
  car3->maxSpeed = 145;
  car3->consumption = 7.0;

  return 0;
}
```

the code compiles normally as: gcc -std=c99 .....

but when I execute return segmentation fault

seems like the structure is not allocated or I access the structure in an improper way.

Comment: Do you understand what a pointer is? What does the pointer `car3` point to? It doesn't point to anything, and trying to access that gives you the segfault.

Comment: "seems like the structure is not allocated " - yes, exactly that. You haven't allocated memory for your car3 pointer to point to.

Comment: `struct cars * car3;` is a pointer to nothing.

Comment: I understand what is a pointer but this is the first time I use it for structures, I think I know how to fix it now. If I write car3 = &car2 then car 3 will point to the structure car2 and will work, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer `car3` has not been set to point to anything, so it value is indeterminate.  When you then attempt to read this invalid value and dereference it as a pointer, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes your code to crash.

You can either point `car3` to an existing struct instance:

```
car3 = &car2;
```

In which case going through `car3` will give you exactly what is stored in `car2`.  Or you can dynamically allocate memory for `car3` to point to:

```
car3 = malloc(sizeof *car3);
```

Then be sure to `free(car3)` when you're done using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line:

```
car3 = malloc(sizeof *car3);
```

This allocates memory for one instance of car.